# Magento Custom Module codePool issue

Tags: magento, module, local

I tried to install extension on a server, and this module have following codePool

```
    <codePool>local</codePool>
```

and it is not working only for that server. but when i change it to following

```
    <codePool>community</codePool>
```

it worked fine. and also transfer the files to community directory.i would like to know the reason why it did not worked. it happened only for that server where Magento 1.7.0.2 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, maybe the problem caused by directory permission

Comment: that was 1st point in my mind, but both local and community directory have same (777) permission.